# Traversing Scalaz Tree

Tags: scala, tree, scalaz, scalaz7

I'm trying to understand the scalaz tree structure and am having some difficulty!

First I've defined a tree:

```
val tree: Tree[Int] =
      1.node(
        2.leaf,
        3.node(
          4.leaf,
          5.leaf))
```

So far using *TreeLoc* I've worked out how to find the *first* element that matches some predicate.  E.g. to find the first node where the value is 3:

```
tree.loc.find(x => x.getLabel == 3)
```

My next challenge was to try and find *all* nodes that match some predicate.  For example I would like to find all leaf nodes (which should be pretty easy using *TreeLoc* and *isLeaf*). Unfortunately I can't for the life of me work out how to walk the tree to do this.

**Edit:** Sorry I don't think I was clear enough in my original question.  To be clear I want to walk the tree in such a way that I have information about the Node available to me.  Flatten, foldRight etc just allow me to operate on [Int] whereas I want to be able to operate on Tree[Int] (or TreeLoc[Int]).

Comment: How do you want the results? The most straightforward approach (if you don't have more specific requirements) would be to use `flatten` on the tree and then filter the resulting `Stream`.

Comment: What type of tree traversal do you want to achieve? It impacts the order of your output (if you actually care about it).

Comment: @TravisBrown: my requirement (sorry I should have been more clear on this) is that I want to walk the nodes not the values.  In this case flatten would give me a Stream of Ints, so you'd have (for example) no way of knowing if the int came from a Node or a Leaf.

Comment: @FedericoPellegatta: At this point the type of traversal doesn't matter as I wouldn't care about the order.

Comment: @d80tb7 Ah. Off the top of my head then I'd probably write something like `tree.cobind(_.foldNode(a => _.isEmpty.option(a))).flatten.flatten` but you might not want multiple traversals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look to how [`find`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.12/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/TreeLoc.scala#L76) is implemented in scalaz, my suggestion is to implement something like:

```scala
implicit class FilterTreeLoc[A](treeLoc: TreeLoc[A]){
  def filter(p: TreeLoc[A] => Boolean): Stream[TreeLoc[A]] =
    Cobind[TreeLoc].cojoin(treeLoc).tree.flatten.filter(p)
}
```

It behaves like the `find` but it gives you back instead a `Stream[TreeLoc[A]]` instead of an `Option[TreeLoc[A]]`.

You can use this as `tree.loc.filter(_.isLeaf)` and `tree.loc.filter(_.getLabel == 3)`.

Note: the use of an implicit class can be obviously avoided if you prefer to have this declared as a method instead.